# Confusing outcome of simple for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have some confusion from the outcome of this simple for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

`console.log` prints value of i from 0 to 9.

However, when I check value of i, dev tools in browser gives me 10.

Can someone explain to me why value of i is 10 here? Condition in my loop (`i < 10`) doesn't allow it to go over 9.

I would get it if I loop an array here. I would have index values and array.length which is always higher than highest index number.

So can anyone explain me what is going on?

[UPDATE] Thank you for your immediate reply and assistance guys! 
I upvoted every correct reply. But "green check mark" went to the person who gave comprehensive answer first.

Comment: What value would be assigned to i, so that i < 10 is false and the loop stops?

Comment: At every iteration value for i is increased and then condition is checked. So to finalize the loop i value is increased to 10, and then checked that it is more than 10, so condition for loop end is met.

Comment: The value of ```i``` goes to 10 but as it doesn't satisfy the condition ```i < 10 ``` so not console inside the loop. You can change ```var i = 0``` to ```let i = 0```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sort of answered your question yourself already:

Your loop condition aborts the loop when `i < 10` no longer holds true. So, thinking about it in reverse, `i` must be `10` or higher for the loop to abort! Therefore, you see `i` having `10` at the end.

This is what happens:

- ...
- `i` is `9`
- `i < 10` is true
- Your loop body executes (for the last time)
- `i++` executes, making `i` `10`
- `i < 10` is no longer true
- Your loop is aborted
- Looking at `i` now, you see `10`, because it got that value 3 steps earlier in my explanation

And if you wonder how you can even see `i` outside the loop: That's because `var` creates function-scoped variables. `i` is available in the whole function, even before your loop (there it's `undefined`) and afterwards. To create a block-scoped variable, you can use `let` instead.

You can see this whole process very clearly in the debugger, if you step through the code (look at the console output, the current position and the `i` variable contents in the watch area to the right):

[image: gif]

Comment: NO if `i` is 9 and it it true it means the execution of the loop should stop there itself and not increment further.

Comment: Why? That doesn't make sense. How would the condition `i < 10` then ever _not_ be true? `9 < 10`... so it continues, but at `10` it stops because `10 < 10` is not true.

Comment: Yes but it checks the conditions and if yes then it will print 10 in hte log

Comment: Please check it in your console.

Comment: Yes, here you can see it works as I said: https://recordit.co/pnJuilGF9S

Comment: As you can see it incremented to 10 and then the condition is false and it jumps out of the loop, then printing 10 outside of it.

Comment: Added a GIF to it

Comment: I'm sorry i misunderstood the concept behind it.

Comment: @CherryDT thank you so much for simple and yet comprehensive respond. You are my hero of the day!

Answer (score 2):

This

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
var i = 0;
while ( i < 10 )
{
  console.log(i);
  i++;
}
```

As you can see, the loop condition is checked first, the incrementation is done then. At the end of the loop, when `i == 9`, the loop is evaluated the last time, `i` is incremented and the condition doesn't hold anymore.

Thus, `i` is `10` when the loop terminates.

Answer (score 2):

You set the loop so that `i` is increased until the condition is true.

Here it is how a for-loop works:

1. Execute initializer (`i=0`)
2. Check condition (is `i <10`?)
3. If true, execute code in loop (`console.log(i)`)
4. Perform the post loop action, in this case `i++`
5. Repeat from point 2 until the condition is no longer true

When `i=9`, the condition is true for the last time (2), the code in loop is executed (3), the post loop action is performed, so that `i=10` (4), the condition is checked again and the loop is terminated since the condition is no longer true.

But now `i=10`.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to [understand the purpose of each the 3 (optional) expressions in a for-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for):

1) *initialization expression*

> An expression (including assignment expressions) or variable
>   declaration evaluated once before the loop begins. Typically used to
>   initialize a counter variable. This expression may optionally declare
>   new variables with var or let keywords. Variables declared with var
>   are not local to the loop, i.e. they are in the same scope the for
>   loop is in. Variables declared with let are local to the statement.
>   The result of this expression is discarded.

2) *condition expression*

> An expression to be evaluated before each loop iteration. If this
>   expression evaluates to true, statement is executed. This conditional
>   test is optional. If omitted, the condition always evaluates to true.
>   If the expression evaluates to false, execution skips to the first
>   expression following the for construct.

3) *final-expression*

> An expression to be evaluated at the end of each loop iteration. This
>   occurs before the next evaluation of condition. Generally used to
>   update or increment the counter variable.

Based on these definitions, it's obvious that when `i == 9` the condition expression will evaluate to `true`, therefore, your final-expression will execute. Seeing as the final-expression increments the `i` by 1, `9` then becomes `10`.